# libjson-c: json_object_object_foreach segmentation fault

Tags: c, json

I am newbie in using libjson-c in Linux.
I have the code below:

```
json_object* new_obj = json_tokener_parse("[{\"abc\": \"123\"}, {\"xyz\": \"456\"}]");
json_object_object_foreach(new_obj, key, val)
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

But the segmentation fault is encountered.

Beside that, the code below is run fine:

```
json_object* my_object = json_object_new_object();
json_object_object_add(my_object, "abc", json_object_new_int(12));
json_object_object_add(my_object, "foo", json_object_new_string("bar"));
json_object_object_add(my_object, "bool0", json_object_new_boolean(0));
json_object_object_add(my_object, "bool1", json_object_new_boolean(1));
json_object_object_add(my_object, "baz", json_object_new_string("bang"));

printf("my_object=\n");
json_object_object_foreach(new_obj, key, val)
{
    printf("\t%s: %s\n", key, json_object_to_json_string(val));
}
```

Please explain me why?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Where* do you get the crash? On which line in your code does it happen? Run in a debugger to find out, and also find out the values of involved variables (like if you're trying to dereference a null pointer).

Answer (score 0):

It crashs at the line `json_object_object_foreach`

I just check and see that, the `json_object_object_foreach` is just applied for json object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The string that you are passing to json_tokener_parse is wrong.

"[{\"abc\": \"123\"}, {\"xyz\": \"456\"}]"

you are using json array of objects so please provide key name to array of objects.

"KEYNAME":[
{ 
.. : ..
},

{
.. : ..
}
]